# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "", even though initialised the string right

Tags: java, arrays, string

currently I'm trying to programm a "Mastermind" programm in my highschool. When compiling, the GUI runs without problems but when I press a certain button, I get a bunch of errors in the console which all seem to be connected to one error (the one you can see in the headline). My teacher also didn't know what went wrong so I thought you guys could take a shot on it. Thank you

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    public Ablaufsteuerung dieAblaufsteuerung;
    private JTextField textMasteFeld [] = new JTextField [4];
    private JTextField textEingabeFeld [][] = new JTextField[8][4];
    private JTextField textBewertungsfeld [][] = new JTextField[8][4];
    private int[] zahlMasterfeld;
    private int eingabeZahl = 0;
    
    public int zeile = 0;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI frame = new GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    


    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GUI() {
        dieAblaufsteuerung= new Ablaufsteuerung(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 669, 436);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblMasterfeld = new JLabel("MasterFeld");
        lblMasterfeld.setBounds(21, 11, 74, 30);
        contentPane.add(lblMasterfeld);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            textMasteFeld[i] = new JTextField();
            textMasteFeld[i].setBounds(9+20*i, 52, 20, 20);
            contentPane.add(textMasteFeld[i]);
            textMasteFeld[i].setColumns(10);
            
        }
        
        JButton btnNeuesSpiel = new JButton("Neues Spiel");
        btnNeuesSpiel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                anzeigenMasterfeld();
            }
        });
        
        btnNeuesSpiel.setBounds(406, 363, 119, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNeuesSpiel);
        
        JLabel lblEingabefeld = new JLabel("EingabeFeld");
        lblEingabefeld.setBounds(255, 19, 105, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblEingabefeld);
        
        for(int zeile = 0; zeile < 8; zeile++){
            for(int spalte = 0; spalte < 4; spalte++){
        
        textEingabeFeld[zeile][spalte] = new JTextField();
        textEingabeFeld[zeile][spalte].setBounds(255+spalte*25, 57+zeile*25, 20, 20);
        contentPane.add(textEingabeFeld[zeile][spalte]);
        textEingabeFeld[zeile][spalte].setColumns(10);
            }
        }
        
        JLabel lblBewertungsfeld = new JLabel("Bewertungsfeld");
        lblBewertungsfeld.setBounds(400, 19, 105, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblBewertungsfeld);
        
        JButton btnber = new JButton("�berpr�fung");
        btnber.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dieAblaufsteuerung.eingebenZahl(zeile);
                zeile++;
            }
        });
        btnber.setBounds(271, 363, 111, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnber);
        
        for(int zeile = 0; zeile < 8; zeile++){
            for(int spalte = 0; spalte < 4; spalte++){
        
        textBewertungsfeld[zeile][spalte] = new JTextField();
        textBewertungsfeld[zeile][spalte].setBounds(400+spalte*25, 57+zeile*25, 20, 20);
        contentPane.add(textBewertungsfeld[zeile][spalte]);
        textBewertungsfeld[zeile][spalte].setColumns(10);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void anzeigenMasterfeld()
    {
        zahlMasterfeld = dieAblaufsteuerung.ausgebenMasterfeld();
            
        for(int i = 0; i < textMasteFeld.length; i++)
        {
            textMasteFeld[i].setText(Integer.toString(zahlMasterfeld[i]));
            
        }
            //textMasteFeld.parseString(zahlMasterfeld);
                
    }
    
    public int[] auslesenEingabeFeld(int zeile)
    {
        String speicher = "";
        
        //String[] speicher = new String[4]; //neu test1 //falsch
        
        int[] zeileEingabeFeld = new int[4];
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            speicher = textEingabeFeld[zeile][i].getText();
            
            //speicher[i] = textEingabeFeld[zeile][i].getText(); //neu test1 //falsch
            
            zeileEingabeFeld[i] = Integer.parseInt(speicher);
            
            //zeileEingabeFeld[i] = Integer.parseInt(speicher[i]); //neu test1 //falsch
        }
        return zeileEingabeFeld;
    }
    
    
    
    public void anzeigenBewertungsfeld(int zeile)
    {
        int[] name = dieAblaufsteuerung.ausgebenBewertung(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            textBewertungsfeld[zeile][i].setText(Integer.toString(name[i]));
        }
        
    }
        
    
}
```

Comment: `Ablaufsteuerung` would be good to post

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) occurs when the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.  Basically, you tried to convert a non-number to a number.  Since you are using primitives (`int`), these cannot be null or blank.

Your message gives you all the details you need.  The String value of `''` cannot assigned to a primitive value of `int`.  Try this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "";
    int myInt = Integer.parseInt(myString);
}
```

You will get the same exception.

You should add handling to your code to either prevent or deal with an empty string before you attempt to set the `int` value.